# Computing $n!\int...\int_{0<s_1<...<s_n}1ds_1...ds_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Compute $n!\int...\int_{0<s_1<...<s_n}ds_1...ds_n$.

Before that, I were to show that $$\int...\int_{0<s_1<...<s_n}f(s_1,s_2-s_1,...,s_n-s_{n-1})ds_1...ds_n=\underset{0<x_1,...,x_n \\ x_1+...+x_n<1}{\int...\int}f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)ds_1...ds_n $$
which I did using a change of variable theorem.

I don't know, however, how to apply it here, if I better apply here. I generally don't know what the bounds for each integral are. I could really use some help.

Comment: For the case of $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=1$, the identity you showed implies that your integral amounts to $$\underset{0<x_1,...,x_n \\ x_1+...+x_n<1}{\int...\int}ds_1\ldots ds_n$$ which is the volume of an $n$-dimensional simplex. I think this can be done as an $n$-times iterated integral, i.e. $$\int_0^1\int_{0}^{1-x_1}\cdots \int_0^{1-x_1-\cdots -x_{n-1}}\,dx_n \cdots  dx_2 dx_1$$

Comment: I did take that into consideration, thank you very much for your insight. I will as well take this volume into account, once I understand how to arrive at that identity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Any permutation of the dummy variables $\ds{\braces{s_{1},\ldots,s_{n}}}$ leaves the integral unchanged. Because there are $n!$ permutations of them, we can write ( the sum $\sum_{P}$ is over the above mentioned possible permutations and $\Theta$ is the *Heaviside Step Function* )

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
n!\int\cdots\int_{0\ <\ s_{1}\ <\ \cdots\ <\ s_{n}\ < 1}
\dd s_{1}\cdots\dd s_{n}}
\\[3mm] = &\
n!\bracks{{1 \over n!}\sum_{P}\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}
\Theta\pars{s_{1}}\Theta\pars{s_{2} - s_{1}}\cdot\Theta\pars{s_{n} - s_{n - 1}}
\dd s_{1}\cdots\dd s_{n}}
\\[3mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}\overbrace{\bracks{%
\sum_{P}\Theta\pars{s_{1}}\Theta\pars{s_{2} - s_{1}}\cdot
\Theta\pars{s_{n} - s_{n - 1}}}}^{\ds{=\ 1}}\ \,\dd s_{1}\cdots\dd s_{n} =
\color{#f00}{1}
\end{align}

In $\underline{\mbox{Many-Body Physics}}$, it's usually written as
$$
\mathcal{T}\int_{0}^{1}\cdots\int_{0}^{1}\dd s_{1}\,\dd s_{n} =
\mathcal{T}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}\dd s}^{n}
$$

where $\mathcal{T}$ is the [Dyson Chronological Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_series).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables, uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$, the integral
$$ \int_{0\leq x_1\leq x_2 \leq \ldots\leq x_n\leq 1} 1\,d\mu $$
computes the probability that $X_1\leq X_2\leq\ldots\leq X_n$, that is obviously $\frac{1}{n!}$, since
$$(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\quad\text{and}\quad (x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)}) $$
have the same probability to occur for any $\sigma\in S_n$, and $|S_n|=n!$.

That proves that the value of your integral is just $\color{red}{\large 1}$.

Comment: Very creative and insightful! Unfortunately, we haven't translated integrals to probability in Analysis III, but I definitely will take a close look at that.

Comment: @Meitar: elements of probability are quite useful in dealing with multiple integrals, I hope it will be a prolific study.